# How to send stream off the Mobile device

Tags: android, kotlin

How to send network stream and packets off the mobile device and these shouldn't be save any where.

I means, upload a file to some server from android studio and it should be save on the server.first goal is to send stream.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.